# Merge 2 chars from UART and convert into HEX value

Tags: avr, uart, avr-gcc, gcc

I receive two characters from the UART:

```
char UD[2] = {'B','8'}
```

I need convert this into a hexadecimal value, like:

```
int a = 0xB8;
```

How can I do that?

I'm using the AVR-GCC.

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) possibly with the "embedded" tag.

Comment: This has something to do with EE as it happens to occur in an embedded environment. I believe this question is on topic as per the discussion [on meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2622/17592).

Comment: "I need a basic tutorial in how to program in C" is not really an EE topic. There is such a thing as computer science, separate from EE, and software separate from hardware. This exact problem could easily occur while, say, programming on Windows 7 using Visual Studio, with identical answers.

Answer (score 3):

One solution could go something like this:

```
// Takes in one of the following characters: "0123456789ABCDEF"
// and returns one of the following integers: 0, 1, 2, ... 13, 14, 15
// No input checking. Use only capital letters.
unsigned int hexCharToInt(char input)
{
    if( '0' <= input && input <= '9')
        return input - '0';
    else
        return input - 'A';
}

// Takes in a two character array ({'0','0'} through {'F','F'}) and constructs
// the corresponding integer. No input checking. Use only capital letters.
unsigned int hexCharArrToInt(char[2] input)
{
    return (hexCharToInt(input[0]) << 4) | hexCharToInt(input[1]);
}

// A general version of the hexCharArrToInt above. Check in to endianess before using
unsigned int arbLenhexCharArrToInt(char[] input, int length)
{
    unsigned int output = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        output |= hexCharToInt(input[i]) << 4*(length-i-1);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You need to change all `int` to `unsigned int`. Left-shifting a signed number is undefined behavior in C.

Comment: Ahh of course, thank you. I guess only changing the return type of hexCharToInt might have sufficed, but I changed them all since it makes more sense to have unsigned int's when working in the hex-value domain.